# How to build strobe media player?

Tags: osmf, strobe-media-playback

I downloaded and installed strobe media player from http://osmf.org/strobe_mediaplayback.html in my MAC. I need to do some debugging using console log statements. How do I build this?

Answer (score 1):

This doc might help: http://osmf.org/dev/osmf/specpdfs/building-osmf.pdf. Otherwise you should have the debug build available from the sourceforge download: http://sourceforge.net/projects/smp.adobe/files/

Hope that helps